# Return true if two strings have common texts in java

Tags: java, string

I have two strings like below. I need to write a function that returns true if they both have common character sequences.

```
String line1 =  "WebElement mainCategory = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='menu-dropdown-icon  dropdown']//a[contains(text(),'"+ dynamicValue +"')]"));";

String line2 = "//li[@class='menu-dropdown-icon  dropdown']//span[contains(text(),'Video camera')]";
```

In the above two strings, since both strings have common text "//li[@class='menu-dropdown-icon  dropdown']//span[contains(text()," I need to print true.

Please advise how to achieve this.

Also note that both the strings are completely dynamic and common strings are not fixed in the position.

Comment: You should read this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: Does not seem a selenium issue if all you want to do is to check a string in another. What have you tried? what its the use case? just checking a string contains another?

Comment: It is not clear what you really want to achieve. Depending on you needs perhaps it is enough to normalize the strings (lowercase, remove unnecessary white space, special characters, ...) tokenize (or not) and then iterate from left to right looking for  equal substrings/tokens. Please explain what you mean by "common text".

Comment: @lauda if the string 1 contains part of string 2 then I'll split the variable name of string 1

Comment: I solved it and my requirement is met without using algorithms... thanks everyone.

Comment: Very good, you can add an answer yourself and mark it as accepted :)